# The server has not found anything matching the requested URI - SSMS

Tags: odbc, azure-sql-database, ssms, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to an Azure db using pyodbc and keep getting this error.

My connection string:

```
"Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;Server=company.database.windows.net;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword;Database=My_Database;UID=DOMAIN\UserName;PWD=********;"
```

Each time I connect it returns error `The server has not found anything matching the requested URI`

The strange thing is that when I try to connect with these credentials from inside SSMS, the error I get is `Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server`.

All the other questions with this error are on web apps and html pages, so I'm very stuck.

Comment: On the failure on SSMS, the Python code implies you want to use Azure Active Directory with Password authentication, but the error in SSMS suggests you're using Windows Authentication. if you want to use the former in SSMS, you need to select "Azure Active Directory - Password" in the Authentication drop down in the connect dialogue window. You're attempting to use 2 different authentication methods here, so it's not surprising you're getting different errors.

Comment: @Larnu "Azure Active Directory - Password" is selected and produces the windows error

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out.

The problem was that I was using `UID=DOMAIN\UserName;`. When I switched it to `UID=username@domain.com;` the connection worked.

Hope this helps someone else with the same problem - there are not many resources on this error.